# How to disable past time with time picker

Tags: antd

Disable past time for today like an hour, minutes, sec etc using ant design. is there any simple solution than 'disabledHours' like minTime etc.

```
<TimePicker format="h:mm:ss A" disabledHours={() => [1, 2, 3]} />
```

Answer (score 13):

You should try to set the disableHours and disabledMinutes of your TimePicker:

```
<TimePicker
    disabledHours={this.getDisabledHours()}
    disabledMinutes={this.getDisabledMinutes()}
>

...
getDisabledHours = () => {
    var hours = [];
    for(var i =0; i < moment().hour(); i++){
        hours.push(i);
    }
    return hours;
}

getDisabledMinutes = (selectedHour) => {
    var minutes= [];
    if (selectedHour === moment().hour()){
        for(var i =0; i < moment().minute(); i++){
            minutes.push(i);
        }
    }
    return minutes;
}
```

And if you want to disable seconds you do the same thing with the `disabledSeconds` function which has a signature of `function(selectedHour, selectedMinute)`.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have already implemented and realized that it will not work out for 24 hours format, isn't? +1 vote for you

Comment: what can i do with OK button that enables when i select hours? because minutes set automatically 00 by default